# How to get debug run in katalon again

Tags: katalon-studio, web-testing, webtest

I used Katalon for web testing for 1 month. But today I'm not seeing the debug run button.

I look it up on the internet but they say that I have to buy a licence.

Is there any way to do it for free?

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Katalon Log Viewer for debuging my Custom Keyword by using following method:

com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil.logInfo()

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You were probably using the one-month free trial version of Katalon Studio Enterprise (KSE).

If you are not planning to buy the license, you can still use the regular Katalon Studio (KS).

> Both Katalon Studio (KS) and Katalon Studio Enterprise (KSE) are two offerings of the Katalon Studio software. KS is the free offering for basic and individual use. KSE is the paid license for teams and professionals to implement on scalable projects.